# How to format a curl API call in VB.NET what to do with the part after the main url

Tags: vb.net, curl

I have a vendor API curl example that I am trying to figure out how to use in VB.net. Note: I was able to do this in a Google Apps Script in a few lines of code and put the result into a sheet but it needs to be in VB.NET. I can connect to the "base" url ok and get a 200 return code with my credentials.

The apps script was really easy:
        var url = 'https://' + TheURL + '/helpdesk/WebObjects/Helpdesk.woa/ra/StatusTypes?' + credentials;

The result showed this should return a json string:

```
    [{"id":1,"type":"StatusType","statusTypeName":"Open"},...
```

This is the curl example from the vendor:

```
    $ curl "https://localhost/helpdesk/WebObjects/Helpdesk.woa\
    > /ra/StatusTypes\
    > ?apiKey=v32lXMFAi7dl3zGrtETArXqKVF8svfAfXZpIwC0P"
```

In VB.NET I add the "/ra/StatusTypes\" bit it breaks - I think there is something I am missing about this API thing in regards to VB.NET, but all the examples are pretty simple.

```
    Dim uri As String = "https://" & TheURL & "/helpdesk/WebObjects/Helpdesk.woa"

    'Dim uri As String = "https://" & TheURL & "/helpdesk/WebObjects/Helpdesk.woa/ra/StatusTypes"  '<< This line does not work
    Dim request As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(LoginID + ":" + APassword)))
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse() ' Get the response.
    Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)   ' Display the status.
    'Console.ReadLine()
    Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
    ' Console.ReadLine()
    reader.Close()
    response.Close()
```